# External crystal;

Tags: external, atmel

I am trying to receive clock by external crystall.

I have my own PCB with ATSAM4SD32CA. XIN and XOUT are connected to external crystall (16MHz). Im try to do that on Keil uvision.

I tryed to make like [here one on github](https://github.com/AtmelUniversityFrance/SAM4S-EK/blob/master/Examples/resources/startup_code/system_sam4s_120MHz.c) I founded but when I use oscilloscope to see on oscillator there is nothing on it. 
But program on "main" function works somehow.

### Thanks a lot for help!

from ASF done function:

```
unsigned int ul_timeout;
    EFC0->EEFC_FMR = EEFC_FMR_FWS(5)|EEFC_FMR_CLOE;
    PMC->CKGR_MOR = (PMC->CKGR_MOR & ~CKGR_MOR_MOSCXTBY) |
                CKGR_MOR_KEY_PASSWD | CKGR_MOR_MOSCXTEN |
                CKGR_MOR_MOSCXTST((15625UL * 32000UL / 8 / 1000000) < 0x100 ?(15625UL * 32000UL / 8 / 1000000) : 0xFF);
        /* Wait the Xtal to stabilize */
        while (!(PMC->PMC_SR & PMC_SR_MOSCXTS));

        PMC->CKGR_MOR |= CKGR_MOR_KEY_PASSWD | CKGR_MOR_MOSCSEL;

    while(!PMC->PMC_SR & PMC_SR_MOSCSELS);
    PMC->PMC_MCKR = (PMC->PMC_MCKR & (~PMC_MCKR_CSS_Msk)) |
            PMC_MCKR_CSS_MAIN_CLK;
    for (ul_timeout = 0x1000; !(PMC->PMC_SR & PMC_SR_MCKRDY);
            --ul_timeout) {
        if (ul_timeout == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    PMC->PMC_MCKR = (PMC->PMC_MCKR & (~PMC_MCKR_PRES_Msk)) | PMC_MCKR_PRES_CLK_1;
    for (ul_timeout = 0x1000; !(PMC->PMC_SR & PMC_SR_MCKRDY);
            --ul_timeout) {
        if (ul_timeout == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
```

main:

```
while(1)
    {
    PIOA->PIO_SODR = PIO_PA28;
    PIOA->PIO_CODR = PIO_PA28;
    }
```

[Oscillograph images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxZbx.png)

Comment: `But program on "main" function works somehow.` So does the Atmel have an internal osc that it is falling back to using? Presumably, if your scope is not broken and shows that the external oscillator isn't working. Perhaps this is more relevant for http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @underscore_d yes, it seems to have one on 4MHz http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-11100-32-bit%20Cortex-M4-Microcontroller-SAM4S_Datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are only 2 pins to connect an external crystal (I guess you mean external crystal and not external oscillator), so the hardware should be OK. Just make sure that you have suitable capacitors to ground.

Here how I usually solve this kind of issue:

1/ Install Atmel Studio 7 (it is free and reliable!)

2/ Create a new GCC ASF board project (user board template)

3/ In the ASF wizard, add the "System clock control" module

4/ In the main function, add sysclk_init():

```
int main (void)
{
    /* Insert system clock initialization code here (sysclk_init()). */
    sysclk_init();
    board_init();

    /* Insert application code here, after the board has been initialized. */
}
```

5/ Set up you clock config in the conf_clock.h. You need to update the macros as you have a 16MHz crystal (the default project supposes a 12MHz crystal):

```
#define CONFIG_SYSCLK_SOURCE        SYSCLK_SRC_PLLACK
#define CONFIG_SYSCLK_PRES          SYSCLK_PRES_2
#define CONFIG_PLL0_SOURCE          PLL_SRC_MAINCK_XTAL
#define CONFIG_PLL0_MUL             15
#define CONFIG_PLL0_DIV             1
#define CONFIG_PLL1_SOURCE          PLL_SRC_MAINCK_XTAL
#define CONFIG_PLL1_MUL             12
#define CONFIG_PLL1_DIV             2
#define CONFIG_USBCLK_SOURCE        USBCLK_SRC_PLL1
#define CONFIG_USBCLK_DIV           2
```

6/ If this is working, check what is the difference between the code in sysclk_init() and your code.

Comment: Hello, Guillaume Michael!
I done what you said. If I correctly understand I done all like SYSCLK_SRC_MAINCK_XTAL and when I try to connect it I have error (Cannot Acess memory) in about 200s (in main is while with 0/1 to some pin) and see https://pp.vk.me/c636227/v636227207/1e27e/rJlnrJs7nfI.jpg this one, I cannot understand where it is and what happend to it. . .

Comment: I tested on oscillograph, on XOUT there are sinus-like but on about 200-600 mV (oscillograph shows 15.9MHz so it works), cannot understand why. on pin I use to debug in main while(1) oscillograph shows me 138kHz so system not use crystall, I havent used scalers and divisions, any, only tryed to use crystall it is. answer of function I used returns 0, so it thinks all is correct. my code is in message of asking.

Comment: I edited my post to show a configuration that should work. If you run step by step your code, which line fails? Do you even reach sysclk_init?

Comment: Yes, I reach sysclk and gone to main, it generates impulses, but sometimes is falls

Comment: not always, so last time I used this code (see oscillograph images on the top) is seems to be stable . . . . . but it would be bad if it wouldnt work sometimes . . .